# Introducing a PHP variable into a Header redirect

Tags: php, html, header, redirect

this is my code:

```
header("Location: ?pid='".$_GET['pid']."'");
die();
```

When I write a simple `echo` `$_GET['pid'];` the value is good but then when I introduce this variable in the header it return something like 27%27 and thats not true true value

When I use `urlencode` the probleme persist:

```
header("Location: ?pid=". urlencode($_GET['pid']);
```

Whats the problem here?

Thank you

Comment: WHAT'S THE ACTUAL VALUE OF `$_GET['pid']`? CAN YOU PLEASE TELL?

Comment: Yes te value is a number 540 for example

Comment: Your problem are single quotes, try redirecting without them: `header("Location: ?pid=".$_GET['pid']);`

Comment: @Nordenheim nop dosent work

Comment: @BorisDetry I hope you got the solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the parameter is being encoded into URL format. Read about `urldecode()` PHP function.

Also, the `%27` is a URL encoded single quote char, therefore you need to remove single quotes from your code:

```
header("Location: ?pid=".$_GET['pid']);
```

If you still however will get `%27` in your header, then I would suggest stripping it out from var by using `trim()` like this:

```
header("Location: ?pid=".trim($_GET['pid'], "'"));
```